# Detecting new line in C

Tags: c

My code goes something like this:

```
char k[1000];
while(1){
scanf("%s",&k);
    if(k[0] == '\n'){
    exit(0);}
/* Do some processing on k */
memset(k,0,1000);
}
```

My intention is to process user input per normal and terminate when user inputs empty string or new line. This doesn't seem to work.

Could you guys help on what went wrong?

On related note, I also want to terminate if it is the end of file, how should I do it for EoF?

Thank you in advance for all the help.

Comment: I'm afraid `scanf` will discard all whitespaces and newlines for you.

Comment: Why are you providing a *pointer to pointer to char* (e.g. `&k`) as the `scanf` pointer for `"%s"`? `k` is already a pointer, so `scanf (" %s", k)` is sufficient.

Comment: Using `scanf("%s"` without width limit leaves you with buffer overflow vulnerability. Always use width limit like `scanf("%999s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off -- don't use `scanf` for user input. It is a minefield of subtle issues just waiting to bite new C programmers, instead use a *line-oriented* input function like `fgets` or POSIX `getline`. Both read up to (and including) the trailing `'\n'` every time (as long as you provide a buffer of sufficient size for `fgets` -- otherwise it just keep reading blocks of characters of its buffer size until it encounters a `'\n'` or `EOF`)

So to read user input until an *empty-string* or `EOF` is encountered, you could simply do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1000

int main (void) {

    char k[MAXC] = "";

    for (;;) {                          /* loop until empty-string of EOF */
        printf ("input: ");             /* prompt for input */
        if (fgets (k, MAXC, stdin)) {   /* read line (MAXC chars max) */
            if (*k == '\n') {           /* test for empty-string */
                fprintf (stderr, "empty-string! bye.\n");
                break;
            }
            size_t l = strlen (k);      /* get length of string */
            if (l && k[l - 1] == '\n')  /* check if last char is '\n' */
                k[--l] = 0;             /* overwrite with nul-terminator */
            printf ("got input: %s\n", k);
        }
        else {  /* got EOF */
            fprintf (stderr, "EOF -- bye.\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
>bin\fgets_user_input.exe
input: this
got input: this
input: is some
got input: is some
input: input
got input: input
input:
empty-string! bye.

>bin\fgets_user_input.exe
input: this is more
got input: this is more
input: ^Z
EOF -- bye. 

>bin\fgets_user_input_cl.exe
input: it works the same
got input: it works the same
input: compiled by gcc
got input: compiled by gcc
input: or by cl.exe (VS)
got input: or by cl.exe (VS)
input:
empty-string! bye.
```

(**note:** for Linux <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> generates the `EOF`, I just happened to be on windoze above)

Answer (score 1):

Like ever so often, the problem here is inappropriate usage of `scanf()`. `scanf()` is not for **reading** input but for **parsing** it and the format-string tells it how to parse.

In your case, `%s` is looking for a sequence of non-whitespace characters (IOW, a word) and it skips any leading whitespace. `\n` (newline) is just a whitespace character, so it is always skipped -- your `scanf()` will just wait for more input until it can parse `%s`.

For more information on `scanf()` pitfalls, I recommend you my [beginners' guide away from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html). As a rule of thumb, with interactive input (which is the default), `scanf()` is almost always wrong.

There's another huge problem with `scanf("%s", ...)`: It will happily overflow **any** buffer you provide it, as long as the input contains non-whitespace characters, just like `gets()` which was even removed from C for exactly that reason: Buffer overflows are extremely dangerous! Therefore always use a field-width, in your case `scanf("%999s", ...)`. This parses a maximum of 999 characters, leaving one for the necessary `0` byte terminating a string.

---

But now for how to do it correctly: There are several functions in C that are indeed for **reading** input and one of them is for reading a *line* of input: `fgets()`. In your code, it would look like this:

```
char k[1000];
while(fgets(k, 1000, stdin)){
    if(k[0] == '\n'){
        exit(0);
    }
    /* Do some processing on k */
    memset(k,0,1000);
}
```

I used your original code here, still some further remarks:

- It would be better to define a macro instead of using the magic number `1000`, e.g. `#define INPUTSIZE 1000` and use this instead, like `char k[INPUTSIZE];`, `fgets(k, INPUTSIZE, stdin)` etc.
- Clearing the whole array is not needed, so to avoid unnecessary work, replace the `memset()` with just `k[0] = '\0';` or similar. A C string ends at the first `0` byte, so this is enough to make `k` hold an *empty string*. If your program does nothing more than shown here, you could even get rid of this completely, as the next `fgets()` call overwrites the array anyways (or returns `NULL` on error, which would stop the loop).

Also note that `fgets()` reads the whole line **including** the newline character at the end, so keep this in mind when processing the contents of `k`.

Comment: Good answer. I would also mention that `memset(k,0,1000);` isn't necessary (not wrong, just not necessary), the OP could simply do `*k = 0;` and insure that `k` is an empty-string.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I tried to be as thorough as possible and still missed that, thanks for the hint :)

Comment: I didn't consider is a miss, there are only about 1000 things that we both could pick up about any given code. But when you see something that is overkill, or just out of place, it's worth dropping a note `:)`

Answer (score -1):

This one is guaranteed to give everything except newlines (and EOFs) for you:

```
char k[1000];
scanf("%[^\n]", k);
```

And when it returns, the next character is guaranteed to be either a newline, or non-existent at all (EOF reached). Get it like this:

```
int next_char = getcgar();
if (next_char == EOF){
    your_eof_process();
}
else if (nexr_char == '\n'){
    your_newline_process();
}
```

---

Personally, I would do it using only `getchar()`:

```
char k[1000];
int ind, tempc;
for (ind = 0; ind < sizeof k; ind ++){
    tempc = getchar();
    if (tempc == '\n'){
        // Some stuff
    }
    else if (tempc == EOF){
        // Other stuff
    }
    else {
        k[ind] = tempc;
    }
}
k[sizeof(k)-1] = '\0';
```

Comment: " the next character is guaranteed to be either a newline, or non-existent at all " or a buffer overrun which is undefined behavior.  Perhaps you want `scanf("%*[^\n]");`

Comment: BTW: `EOF` is not defined to be -1, even though it often is.  Just use `EOF`.